# Applescript Notifications

Tags: button, notifications, applescript

1. Is there a specific way to code a notification with buttons?
2. Also is there a way to keep the notification there until a button is pressed?

Regards,
SuperTech

Comment: Have you looked at [display dialog](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW120)?

Comment: 1.) No - 2.) No

Comment: You mean a Dialog or a notification from notification Center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way.

Thanks for that @vadian .

SuperTech